# Проверка на опечатку в input-е на основе данных из БД

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Есть input от [мультиселекта](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/) в форме, который ищет логины при вводе. На сервере получаю и добавляю в него логины при загрузке страницы. Но проблема в том, что если я опечатаюсь в слове, то его не найдёт. Как можно выводить *"Возможно вы имели ввиду Иван, а не Кван"* и добавить проверку на это? Заводить специальный массив с возможным ошибочным написанием? :) Мультиселект использую для функционала поиска и вывода. Можно было написать свой поисковик для таких целей, но мне понравился от bootstrap. Спасибо.

Код:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src = "js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src = "js/init.js"></script>

<form class="forma" action="Deleted.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select id="example-post" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple">
          <?php
           $names = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM names");
           while ($rr = $names->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option value=\"".$rr['id']."\">".$rr['name']."</option>";
           }
          ?>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Выбрать"></input>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Инициализация мультиселекта:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-post').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        filterPlaceholder: 'Search here'
    });
    $('.glyphicon-remove-circle').addClass("fa fa-times");
    $(".multiselect-container .input-group").css('margin','0px');
    $(".multiselect-container>li>a>label").css('padding', '3px 20px 3px 15px');
    $(".multiselect-container .input-group").css('display', 'flex');
    $(".multiselect-container .input-group>.form-control").css('width', '75%');           
    $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:first)").each(function() {
      $(this).attr({
        name: 'checkMess[]',
        id: $(this).attr('value'),
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: Подгружать из базы  like и выводить раскрывающимся списком. есть в инете готовые решения

Comment: В примере мультиселекта по ссылке из вашего вопроса, если набрать land, всё равно подставит Poland в варианты. Знач и с Иваном - ваном будет работать

Comment: @Bloom, Что-то мне подсказывает, что это на БД нагрузка большая будет и с like как?

Comment: @Kirill, Да, но если ввести Polanr или с любой другой опечаткой, то нет